# Unable to click Button on Popup Window (with about:blank) with Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, popup

I am trying to click a button using **Python Selenium** that appears on a [Popup or Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kAz93.png) (where the url is shown as **about:blank**) which shows up at some point in the process, and I need to **click Yes/No on this Window**. ****However**, I cannot** do so even if I switch to the new window. Using `driver.window_handles`, it seems to me this Popup is a `Window` and not an `iframe` as I can switch to it with `driver.switch_to.window()`. However, I cannot click the button Yes/No. Inspecting the "Yes" in the [HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sTEfX.png) code of the Popup/Window, here is how I try to click it in my code. `driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'div[onclick="javascript:self.opener.document.forms[0].operation.value = document.resultForm.operation.value;window.close();self.opener.showProgressAndSubmit();"]').click()`

What happens when I try this is that the code just freezes, and nothing happens even in Debugging mode.

When I manually do these steps (and not with Selenium), even a simple click of `Enter` does the job for me. However, in Selenium `Enter` also does **not** work.

What am I doing wrong here?

P.S: The code that generates the Yes/No Box is `<div onclick="document.inqPrinPage.operation.value='submit'; document.inqPrinPage.submit();" class="Button">Submit</div>`

Here is the Full HTML Code of the Popup Window.

```html
<html><head>
  <title>Warning!</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" ;="" charset="iso-8859-1">
  <style type="text/css"></style>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="webapp/styles/common.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
  <!--
  var defaultAction;
      function catchkey() { 
           if (event.keyCode == 13) { 
               eval(defaultAction); 
           } 
      } 
  // --> 
  </script>
  </head>
  <body onkeypress="catchkey()">
    <form name="resultForm">
      <input type="hidden" name="operation" value="confirmSubmit"> 
      <table class="Text" border="0" width="100%">
        <tbody><tr height="50">
          <td width="50%" colspan="2" align="center" class="PageTitle">
                Warning!</td></tr>
        <tr class="Text">
          <td width="50%" colspan="2" align="left">A worldwide search will be performed. <br>Do you wish to continue? <p>Select Yes to submit the inquiry. <br>Select No to search specific regions and/or countries.
          </p><p></p></td></tr>
        <tr height="50">
           <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">  defaultAction = 'javascript:self.opener.document.forms[0].operation.value = document.resultForm.operation.value;window.close();self.opener.showProgressAndSubmit();'</script>
        <td width="50%" align="center">
             <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
               <tbody><tr>
                 <td height="16"><img height="17" border="0" src="webapp/images/roundedLeftCap.jpg"></td>
                 <td valign="middle" height="14"><div onclick="javascript:self.opener.document.forms[0].operation.value = document.resultForm.operation.value;window.close();self.opener.showProgressAndSubmit();" class="Button"> &nbsp;Yes</div></td>
                 <td height="16"><img height="17" border="0" src="webapp/images/roundedRightCap.jpg"></td>
               </tr></tbody></table></td>
        <td width="50%" align="center">
             <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
               <tbody><tr>
                 <td height="16"><img height="17" border="0" src="webapp/images/roundedLeftCap.jpg"></td>
                 <td valign="middle" height="14"><div onclick="javascript:window.close();" class="Button"> &nbsp;No</div></td>
                 <td height="16"><img height="17" border="0" src="webapp/images/roundedRightCap.jpg"></td>
               </tr></tbody></table></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody></table>
    </form>
  

</body></html>
```

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this.

Comment: Read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246104/discussion-between-dimitri-and-aaron).

Comment: Can you separate `el = driver.find_element(...)` and `el.click()` with `print` statements before and after each operation, to see which operation freezes?

Comment: it freezes on the `el = driver.find_element(...)` section

Comment: What is weird that after I switch to this window with `driver.switch_to.window()` `print(driver.current_url)` also freezes.

Comment: @aaron, I suspect there is an issue with the fact that this window is **about:blank**. Any ideas how to approach this, given this information?

Comment: Try `options.page_load_strategy = 'none'` before passing `options` in `webdriver.Chrome(..., options=options)`. (You might need `WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda d: d.execute_script('return document.readyState') == 'complete')` after `driver.get(...)`.)

Comment: @aaron, amazing!!!!. `options.page_load_strategy = 'none'` did the job! Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per @aaron's suggestion, simply adding `options.page_load_strategy = 'none'` to the beginning (and then obviously properly calibrating the wait times for the other elements - for me `WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.number_of_windows_to_be(n))` was sufficient) did the trick to resolve the issue with freezing when interacting with the `about:blank` popup window.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't have used the `onclick` attribute - it is too long, and fragile.

Try the following xpath expressions

- `//td/div[contains(text(), "Yes")]`
- `//td/div[@class="Button" and contains(text(), "Yes")]` (more precise search)

Comment: what exactly is the syntax here? 
`driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'div[@class="Button" and contains(text(), "Yes")]')` **still freezes**

Comment: It's XPath expression, full syntax is `driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//div[@class="Button" and contains(text(), "Yes")]')`

Comment: the moment I switch to `driver.switch_to.window(handle)` and run `driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//div[@class="Button" and contains(text(), "Yes")]')`, it again **freezes** like with the other attempts.

Could the whole problem have to do with the fact that this window is an **"about:blank"**?

Comment: @Dimitri please provide Python code

Comment: I have all the code in the original post. What else would you want to see?

Comment: I see the HTML only where is the Python code?